# Convert R data frame into list of vectors

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame (imported from an Excel worksheet where I have written a lists of strings row by row) and want to convert the rows into a list of vectors where each vector contains the non-missing cell values for that row:

eg:

```
#Sample data frame
dfX <- data.frame(C0 = c(1,2,3),
              C1 = c("Apple","Apple","Pear"),
              C2 = c("Banana","Orange", "Lemon"),
              C3 = c("Pear","Melon", ""))
```

Which would be used to generate the following list:

```
myList = list(c("Apple","Banana", "Pear"),
          c("Apple","Orange", "Melon"),
          c("Pear","Lemon"))
```

Note the third vector is truncated to two elements as the cell contains an empty string. Also note that the index (C0) is dropped.

I have seen some examples which convert the data frame to a matrix and use the split function to then paste the results into the global environment, e.g.

```
list2env(setNames(split(as.matrix(dfX),
                    row(dfX)), paste0("Row",1:3)),
                    envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

But I was wondering if there were (a) a newer tidyverse function for handling this and (b) a way to populate straight to a list (I later want to lapply a function against that list).  Also want the missing values handling on the way into the list if possible!

Comment: `data.frame` is effectively a list of vectors. So, `class(dfX) <- "list"`

Comment: Or `as.list(dfX)`.  Either way, it would be probably make your life easier to convert the empty strings into `NA_character_` first.  If you're reading your data in from csv, note the handy argument `na.strings` to do this during the import.

Comment: @Khashaa That does not reproduce OPs expected output; OP is after a row-wise (not column-wise) operation. Your solution turns a `data.frame` into a `list` of column vectors. OP wants a `list` of row vectors.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Didn't notice the rows were transposed. `gather(dfX, var, val, -C0) %>% spread(C0, val) %>% map(c)`
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are interested in `tidyverse` way, one option would be

```
library(tidyverse)

dfX %>%
  group_split(C0) %>% #Or use split(.$C0) if `dplyr` is not updated
  map(~discard(flatten_chr(.), . == "")[-1])

#[[1]]
#[1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Pear"  

#[[2]]
#[1] "Apple"  "Orange" "Melon" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "Pear"  "Lemon"
```

`group_split` is available in `dplyr 0.8.0`. Also this assumes that you would have unique `C0` in every row and for every row we `discard` any value which is equal to empty strings ("").

---

Or in base R combination of `split` and `lapply` would also work.

```
lapply(split(dfX[-1], dfX$C0), function(x) x[x != ""])

#$`1`
#[1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Pear"  

#$`2`
#[1] "Apple"  "Orange" "Melon" 

#$`3`
#[1] "Pear"  "Lemon"
```

---

Another base R option is `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
apply(dfX[-1], 1, function(x) x[x!= ""])
```

Comment: I tried the tidyverse version but my version of dplyr is not updated and the commented version threw an error.  Went with the first base R solution (split and lapply) and it did the job.

I'm a little surprised that tidyverse doesn't have a function to turn a row (or column) object into a vector of strings?

Comment: @BrisbanePom that's why `group_split` was introduced. Pretty strange that it did not work. Maybe because it is a factor? Can you convert it into character and then check. `dfX %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  split(.$C0) %>% 
  map(~discard(flatten_chr(.), . == "")[-1])` works for me on the sample data provided.

Answer (score 2):

A base R option is `by`

```
by(dfX, dfX$C0, function(x) unlist(x[x != ''][-1]))
#dfX$C0: 1
#[1] "Apple"  "Banana" "Pear"
#------------------------------------------------------------
#dfX$C0: 2
#[1] "Apple"  "Orange" "Melon"
#------------------------------------------------------------
#dfX$C0: 3
#[1] "Pear"  "Lemon"
```

`by` returns a "dressed" list, ignoring the attributes this is the same as your expected `myList`.

Comment: No problem +1, `by` is combination of `split + lapply` in one function.